getting error when making CDE gui for fedora 40
I had run ./autogen.sh and ./configure like the README.md file said and I have all the dependencies (I assume), but when i run make the end output is this:



`
 ibtool: compile:  c++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../../include -DANSICPP -DMULTIBYTE -DNLS16 -D_POSIX_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_SVID_SOURCE -DUSE_XINERAMA -DUSE_XRENDER -DHAS_PAM_LIBRARY -I../../../lib -g -O2 -Wno-unused-result -Wno-write-strings -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-format-truncation -pthread -MT libapi_la-api_api.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libapi_la-api_api.Tpo -c api_api.C  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libapi_la-api_api.o
In file included from ../../../lib/util/tt_object.h:36,
                 from ../../../lib/mp/mp_global.h:39,
                 from ../../../lib/mp/mp_c_global.h:44,
                 from ../../../lib/mp/mp_c.h:36,
                 from api_api.C:45:
../../../lib/util/tt_ptr.h:44:10: fatal error: rpc/rpc.h: No such file or directory
   44 | #include <rpc/rpc.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[5]: *** [Makefile:535: libapi_la-api_api.lo] Error 1
make[5]: Leaving directory '/home/rio/Downloads/cde-2.5.2/lib/tt/lib/api/c'
make[4]: *** [Makefile:440: all-recursive] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/rio/Downloads/cde-2.5.2/lib/tt/lib/api'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:600: all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/rio/Downloads/cde-2.5.2/lib/tt/lib'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:440: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/rio/Downloads/cde-2.5.2/lib/tt'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:442: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rio/Downloads/cde-2.5.2/lib'
make: *** [Makefile:587: all-recursive] Error 1
rio@fedorabeta:~/Downloads/cde-2.5.2$ `





(I didn't press anything during the make)
TL;DR I tried to compile a GUI for GNU + Linux Fedora but it gave out error.
edit: fixed the original problem but new one arose
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/rio/Downloads/cde-2.5.2/lib/tt/lib/util'
Making all in tttk
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/rio/Downloads/cde-2.5.2/lib/tt/lib/tttk'
/bin/sh ../../../../libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=compile c++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../include   -DANSICPP -DMULTIBYTE -DNLS16 -D_POSIX_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_SVID_SOURCE -DUSE_XINERAMA -DUSE_XRENDER -DHAS_PAM_LIBRARY  -DTT_VERSION_STRING=\""CDE Version 2.5.2"\" -I../ -I../../lib -g -O2 -DOPT_TIRPC -I/usr/include/tirpc -Wno-unused-result -Wno-write-strings -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-format-truncation        -pthread -MT libtttk_la-ttdesktop.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libtttk_la-ttdesktop.Tpo -c -o libtttk_la-ttdesktop.lo `test -f 'ttdesktop.C' || echo './'`ttdesktop.C
libtool: compile:  c++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../../../include -DANSICPP -DMULTIBYTE -DNLS16 -D_POSIX_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_SVID_SOURCE -DUSE_XINERAMA -DUSE_XRENDER -DHAS_PAM_LIBRARY "-DTT_VERSION_STRING=\"CDE Version 2.5.2\"" -I../ -I../../lib -g -O2 -DOPT_TIRPC -I/usr/include/tirpc -Wno-unused-result -Wno-write-strings -fno-strict-aliasing -Wno-format-truncation -pthread -MT libtttk_la-ttdesktop.lo -MD -MP -MF .deps/libtttk_la-ttdesktop.Tpo -c ttdesktop.C  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/libtttk_la-ttdesktop.o
ttdesktop.C:49:10: fatal error: X11/Intrinsic.h: No such file or directory
   49 | #include <X11/Intrinsic.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[4]: *** [Makefile:501: libtttk_la-ttdesktop.lo] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/rio/Downloads/cde-2.5.2/lib/tt/lib/tttk'
make[3]: *** [Makefile:600: all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/rio/Downloads/cde-2.5.2/lib/tt/lib'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:440: all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/rio/Downloads/cde-2.5.2/lib/tt'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:442: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rio/Downloads/cde-2.5.2/lib'
rio@fedorabeta:~/Downloads/cde-2.5.2$                                                                  


You need to install the glibc-devel package on your Fedora system if you want to build software.

I already have it installed

Hm.  That's where it comes from on Debian/Ubuntu.  I guess Red Hat/Fedora is different.  Some googling of this error suggests that installing the libtirpc-devel package may be what you need.

I did then ran make clean and then made it again but it seemed to have no effect

well I kinda fixed it by running rpm -qlp libtirpc-devel-1.1.4-3.el8.x86_64.rpm | grep rpc.h /usr/include/tirpc/rpc/rpc.h and ./autogen.sh but a new problem arose
fatal error: X11/Intrinsic.h: No such file or directory

Looks like the source code you're trying to build expects a very old, obsolete environment.  It will require some serious elbow grease on your part to get it all working.  X11 intrinsics means this is an X application, so you'll need to install X11 development libraries and make sure your system supports X applications using Xwayland if you don't run X natively, etc.
